# Magento2 :Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService

Tags: magento2, chrome-browser, mftf, selenium

I've been trying to implements functional testing in magento using mftf i followed the same steps from this [documenation](https://devdocs.magento.com/mftf/docs/getting-started.html)

but i keep getting :

> [Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownErrorException] unknown error:
> Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.   (unknown error:
> DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)   (The process started from
> chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so
> ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) Build info:
> version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time:
> '2018-11-14T08:25:53' System info: host: 'ubuntu', ip: '127.0.1.1',
> os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.8.0-41-generic',
> java.version: '1.8.0_275' Driver info: driver.version: unknown remote
> stacktrace: #0 0x55d212e1e199

- chrome driver: 88.0.4324.96
- chrome browser: 88.0.4324.96
- selenium : selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar

I don't know how to fix it I've tried even changing my java to 11 but it's the same.

is there anyone familiar with this error, please.

```
xvfb-run java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/bin/chromedriver -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar  -debug
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added `"--headless","--no-sandbox"` in dev/tests/acceptance/tests/functional.suite.yml